# calling a webservice by php -> error : no transport found or selected transport is not yet supported

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

**Error: no transport found, or selected transport is not yet supported!**

when I call a webservice this error will happen.

here's my code:

```
include("lib/bankmellat/nusoap.php");
$client = new \bankmellat\nusoap_client('https://pgwstest.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl');
$namespace = 'http://interfaces.core.sw.bps.com/';
$parameters = array();
$parameters['terminalId'] = $terminalId;
$parameters['userName'] = $userName;
.
.
.
$result = $client->call('bpPayRequest', $parameters , $namespace);
echo '<h2>Error!!</h2><pre>' . $client->getError(); . '</pre>';
```

*ubuntu 12.04*

*apache2*

*PHP 5.3.10*

*cURL Enabled on php - version : 7.21.3*

*cURL supported protocols : dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp*

I must say that I implemented this code on another servers with almost similar qualifications and they are working still!

Please help to fix this..guys! thnx.

Answer (score 5):

finally I find out my problem!
major problem were the **php version(5.3.10)!**

according to [php manual on constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)  :

*As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.*

so I changed the **nusoap_client** (the old constructor style) function in nusoap_client class to **__construct** and problem fixed!

now I got another error and working on to fix it:

**wsdl error: Getting https://pgws.bpm.blabla.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: Unknown scheme**

Comment: my second problem solved by changing the other **old constructors** to **__construct** syntax!

Comment: where you change after change to __constructor pleas help me

Answer (score 1):

when use namespace , old php OOP (php4) construct not run auto . 
add __construct method to all class .
after call old construct in the new __construct method .

or use this edited file > [nusoap_client.php](http://wikisend.com/download/501382/nusoap_client.php)